# How to stop program from exiting itself out?

Tags: ruby

my question regards the programming language of Ruby and the Ruby program.

After using this code:

```
print "What's your first name?" 
first_name = gets.chomp
first_name.capitalize!

print "What's your last name?" 
last_name = gets.chomp
last_name.capitalize!

print "What city are you from?" 
city = gets.chomp
city.capitalize!

print "What state or province are you from?" 
state = gets.chomp
state.upcase!

print "Your name is #{first_name} #{last_name} and you're from #{city}, #{state}!"
```

After the program asks for the state or province and I enter in a value, the program automatically exits itself out.

I am using RubyInstaller for Windows (version Ruby 1.9.3-p545).
I used Notepad++ to type the code and saved it under the Ruby .rb extension.

I ran the program by double-clicking the file from where I saved it.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You mean to say that the command terminal which opens and runs the program immediately closes when the code terminates?

Comment: Since its windows and they are double clicking the file to run it, I'm assuming a terminal window pops up and when they enter the last bit on info the terminal closes since the execution is done. @zCoding try adding a `sleep 10` at the end of your script. It'll delay the window closing.

Comment: If you open the command prompt (terminal) and execute your ruby code from there (not double-click it), it will remain open after running:  `C:\> ruby C:\path\to\your\code.rb`

Comment: Hmm, if I add "sleep 10," the program closes after a certain amount of time.

If I run the file in the Command Prompt, the program runs in the Command Prompt.

How can I make it so that the file runs on its own program and doesn't exit until I command for it to exit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way is to add this at the end:

```
puts "Press RETURN when you're done."
gets
```

Comment: This is the best advice that I have received so far! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* the end of the program, there are no more user questions to be answered at that point. So what do you want your program to do after it asks you for state/province and repeats your data to you?

You might want to change `print` to `puts` though.

EDIT: As Michael and Leo say in comments, if you start your program by double-clicking the file in Windows, it will open a terminal, run your program, and close the terminal as soon as the program is done. The program *is* repeating the information back in a sentence with the valoues in the sentence; but that information is on your screen only for a split second, before Windows closes your program's terminal. Leo and Michael each suggest a way (run from terminal or insert a `sleep` statement); another way similar to Leo's is having another `gets` at the end and asking the user to hit Enter when they are done reading.

Comment: Hmm, what I am requesting the program to do is to ask for data (name, city, state...) Then repeat the information back in a sentence with the values in the sentence (last line of code at the end).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried from your command to run

```
irb code.rb
```

Assuming your file name is code.rb

Also as suggests try `puts` instead of `print`

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop still works

```
while true
  'something'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

print"What's your first name?"
first_name=gets.chomp
first_name.capitalize!

print"What's your last name?"
last_name=gets.chomp
last_name.capitalize!

print"What city are you from?"
city=gets.chomp
city.capitalize!

print"What state are you from?"
state=gets.chomp
state.upcase!

puts"Your name is #{first_name},your last name is #{last_name}, and your from #{city},#{state}!"

Works

Comment: I don't think this is really answering the question about the programming exiting.